# Margin dp unit not scale layout correctly in differents screens

Tags: android, scale

I have simple tableLayout which show the problem with independent unit dp.

I suppose that with dp unit in my **layout_margin** attribute - layout will be resized without problem on any device.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="40dp"
    >

<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 
<TextView 
android:text="@string/start_login_username"
android:id="@+id/start_login_username" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>


<EditText 
android:id="@+id/start_login_EditTxt1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
/>

</TableRow>


<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView 
android:text="@string/start_login_password"
android:id="@+id/start_login_password" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>


<EditText 
android:id="@+id/start_login_EditTxt2" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="textPassword"
/>

</TableRow>


<TableRow android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button android:text="@string/start_login_cancel"
android:id="@+id/start_login_cancel" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

</Button>


<Button
android:text="@string/start_login_login"
android:id="@+id/start_login_ButtonLogin" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

</Button>


</TableRow>



</TableLayout>
```

But, testing this layout, we can see that dp is not so independent in layout margin .

**Here the screenshot in Samsung Nexus(Good scale):**

[image: Samsung Galaxy]

**Here the screenshot in LG Optimus GT 540(Bad scale):**

[image]

Im looking the similar threads in StackOverflow, and possible solution, to have correct scale on any screen is:

- Not use margin and padding at all, but use always tableLayout and add
  moc Views with some weight, to add space between Views(not good because of
  pollution of xml layouts. Anyway, its looks promising ).
- Make my own calculation of independent unit, and rescale all programmatically (not good for me because I have all in xml's)
- Use different layouts for differents screens (not good because Im too lazy to recreate the layout for each my view and supporting them)

**Questions:**

How can I solve the problem with scaling of my layout for all screens using the same layout ?

How I can make margin works correct on my screens ?

What you think about my two solutions. This is good practice ? (specially first one) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply use linearlayout with weight attributes, remember to set width="0dp" if it is the width you want to be automatically adjusted.

Your xml should be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"  >

    <TextView
        android:text="Your name"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:minWidth="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```